# Data is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, put

I have this code that takes the data, shows in the html and updates it, however the data is undefined here:

```
data: {
    id: clickedBox.data('id'),
    nome: clickedBox.data('nome'),
    email: clickedBox.data('email')
}
```

The full code below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    //async: false,
    url: 'https://app.myurl.com/reservas',
    success:function(reservas){

        reservas.forEach (function (reserva) {
            var reservasHTML = [];


            reservasHTML.push('<tr class="reservas">');
            reservasHTML.push('<td> <input type="checkbox" class="salvar" data-id="' + reserva._id + '" data-nome="' + reserva.nome + '" data-email="' + reserva.email + '"/> </td>');
            reservasHTML.push('<td>' + reserva._id + '</td>');
            reservasHTML.push('<td>' + reserva.nome + '</td>');
            reservasHTML.push('<td>' + reserva.email + '</td>');
            reservasHTML.push('</tr>');

            $('tbody').append(reservas.join(""));

        })
    },
    error:function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});


$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.salvar', function(){
       alert('Salvo!');
       var clickedBox = $(this);

       $.ajax({

            type: 'PUT',
            url: 'http://localhost/datas',
            //async: false,
            data: {
                id: clickedBox.data('id'),
                nome: clickedBox.data('nome'),
                email: clickedBox.data('email')
            },
            sucess:function (success) {
                console.log('success')
            },
            error:function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If anyone can help me or direct me. I'm stuck in this for hours :X

Thanks :)

Comment: Any errors in the console? Check your generated html inputs.. do those contain what you expect?

Comment: I assume your talking about clickedBox.data? If so please show where you define clickedBox. Also undefined means the thing your referencing was never defined, this is often caused by scope issues. For nome do you mean name?

Comment: what does `clickedbox` mean?

Comment: Yesss... I'm Brazilian.. haha

my html input it's like this:

td> <input type="checkbox" class="salvar" data-id="' + reserva._id + '" data-nome="' + reserva.nome + '" data-email="' + reserva.email + '"/> </td>

I'm creating it inside the get request..

Comment: I have sometimes have issues with using jQuerys `.data`.  Though it does read the `data-` attributes it keeps it's own copy of the data.  You might try using `.attr('data-id');`.

Comment: Yes Gary, I just realized that I forgot to put the data attr on my tag --".. THANKS EVERYBODY! :D